# Вывод модального окна, после отправки формы

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. У меня есть форма резюме и после нажатия на `<button>` форма должна отправляться на почту, а потом выводится модальное окно где будет агитация подписаться на соц. сети. Я вывод по нажатию сделал, но сама форма не отправляется. Вообще все работает, т.е. отправляется форма , на почту все приходит и т.д. только с модальным окном проблема и все.

```
        @push('scripts')
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() { // вся мaгия пoсле зaгрузки стрaницы
                $('button#go').click( function(event){ // лoвим клик пo кнопке с id="go"
                    event.preventDefault(); // выключaем стaндaртную рoль элементa
                    $('#overlay').fadeIn(400, // снaчaлa плaвнo пoкaзывaем темную пoдлoжку
                        function(){ // пoсле выпoлнения предъидущей aнимaции
                            $('#modal_form')
                                .css('display', 'block') // убирaем у мoдaльнoгo oкнa display: none;
                                .animate({opacity: 1, top: '50%'}, 200); // плaвнo прибaвляем прoзрaчнoсть oднoвременнo сo съезжaнием вниз
                        });
                });
                /* Зaкрытие мoдaльнoгo oкнa, тут делaем тo же сaмoе нo в oбрaтнoм пoрядке */
                $('#modal_close, #overlay').click( function(){ // лoвим клик пo крестику или пoдлoжке
                    $('#modal_form')
                        .animate({opacity: 0, top: '45%'}, 200,  // плaвнo меняем прoзрaчнoсть нa 0 и oднoвременнo двигaем oкнo вверх
                            function(){ // пoсле aнимaции
                                $(this).css('display', 'none'); // делaем ему display: none;
                                $('#overlay').fadeOut(400); // скрывaем пoдлoжку
                            }
                        );
                });
            });
        </script>
        @endpush
```

Файл отправляющий форму на мыло

```
    public function __construct(QuestionnaireFormRequest $request)
{
    $this->request = $request;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->subject('Резюме c сайта stewardjob.ru')
        ->view('emails.questionnaire')->with([
            'name' => $this->request->name,
            'old'  => $this->request->old,
            'phone' => $this->request->phone,
            'social_link'  => $this->request->social_link,
            'graph' => $this->request->graph,
            'city' => $this->request->city,
            'additionally'  => $this->request->additionally,
        ]);
}}
```

Comment: Переформулируйте ваш вопрос т.к. неясно, в чем именно проблема.

Comment: Ну вот я нажимаю на кнопку форма отправляется, когда модальное окно добавил, то при нажатии на кнопку окно открывается, а форма не отправляется.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что кнопка `go` у вас `submit` по всей видимости, а вы делаете `event.preventDefault();` - что отменяет отправку формы. И внесу немного ясности, если вы отправите форму - страница перезагрузится и вашей модалки - как не бывало. Предлагаю переделать отправку формы на `ajax`, а внутри него уже делать отображение модалки после успешного завершения в `success`.

Comment: Я просто в js новичек, спасибо, попробую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А где сама форма? ajax'ом отправляете?

Если нет, то в контроллере после обработки формы сделайте

```
return back()->with('status', 'Успех');
```

В ввиде сделайте проверку,есть ли сессия с именем status и если есть выводите окно с предложение подписаться.

```
@if(session()->has('status'))
    //тут код отображения предложения подписаться
@endif
```

Если ajax'om ,то после успешной обработки ответа выводите свою модаль с предложением подписаться